# Python Incorrect Boolean Evaluation

Tags: python, boolean

Python does not seem to want to return the correct answer on this loop. I believe the code should stop after the evaluation of t=1.8 as the next value of t, 2.0, is equal to b, not less than.

```
a=0.0
b=2.0
h=0.2
t=a
print "t = ",t
while t<b:
    t+=h;
    print "t = ",t;
```

The output is

```
t =  0.0
t =  0.2
t =  0.4
t =  0.6
t =  0.8
t =  1.0
t =  1.2
t =  1.4
t =  1.6
t =  1.8
t =  2.0
t =  2.2
```

Any help or recognition of an error would be massively appreciated.

Comment: Since you are using floating point, you can't rely on the *equality* of two numbers, as there is always some floating point imprecision. [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Hi @EugeneSh. i just uploaded the output as well. I agree, but this seems to be a quite significant error. Thanks for the link!

Comment: The opposite is true, it is a very *small* error. You can see that eventually `2.0 < 2.0`. And it's because it could be  evaluated as `1.9999999 < 2.0` or similar

Comment: You can see this by changing your `print` statement to `print "t = {:.30f}".format(t)`

Comment: Very Helpful! Thanks for the insight @ThisSuitIsBlackNot